# how to make clicking feeling on mobile with css

Tags: css, mobile

I have been thinking for a long time, but I have not found a solution. Some mobile sites have a hover-like clicking feeling when they click on links and buttons. However, the ': hover' or ': active' properties were not used when I viewed the css files.

For example: http://m.vw.com.tr/ticariarac/ana-sayfa.aspx

You can log in from your mobile device and hold down the buttons to understand what I mean.

How can I do that?

Comment: ... Javascript can do that pretty easily.

Comment: but i do not know how to do this :) can you help me or you can give me some example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your simple example :

```js
simulateHover = function(element) {
  if (element.className.includes(' active')) { 
    element.className = element.className.replace(' active', '')
  } else {
    element.className += ' active';
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 12px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  background: darkcyan;
  transition: background 225ms ease-in-out;
}

.onhover:hover,
.active {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="onhover">Hover me</div>

<div class="onclick" onclick="simulateHover(this)">Click me</div>
```

Comment: thanks, was very helpful. I thought it could be done with different methods, but this is enough.